# Adjusting the spaces to look better?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The following output looks so dense. Could you make it more loose in both vertical and horizontal?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\let\temp\underbrace
\def\underbrace#1_#2{{\color{red}\temp{{\color{black}#1}}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\begin{aligned}
x^2+6x+10 
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{+2x (3)}_{+2ab} + 10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{+2x (3)}_{+2ab} \underbrace{+(3)^2 -(3)^2}_{+b^2-b^2} +10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2+2x(3)+(3)^2}_{a^2+2ab+b^2}  -(3)^2 +10\\
&= \underbrace{(x+3)^2}_{(a+b)^2} -9 +10\\
&= (x+3)^2+1
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any constructive suggestions, advice, ideas, etc are always welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `\mathstrut` to cover the most common cases avoiding phantoms; also `\textcolor` is better than `\color` in math mode.

You need to add `{}` in front of `+` to get decent spacing. I also added a couple of thin spaces for separating the braces.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\let\latexunderbrace\underbrace
\def\underbrace#1_#2{%
  {\,\textcolor{red}{\latexunderbrace{\textcolor{black}{\mathstrut#1}}_{#2}}\,}%
}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\begin{aligned}
x^2+6x+10 
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{{}+2x (3)}_{+2ab} + 10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{{}+2x (3)}_{+2ab} \underbrace{+(3)^2 -(3)^2}_{+b^2-b^2} +10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2+2x(3)+(3)^2}_{a^2+2ab+b^2}  -(3)^2 +10\\
&= \underbrace{(x+3)^2}_{(a+b)^2} -9 +10\\
&= (x+3)^2+1
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly better version where the space in front of the + is removed

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\let\latexunderbrace\underbrace
\def\underbrace#1_#2{%
  {\,\textcolor{red}{\latexunderbrace{\textcolor{black}{\mathstrut#1}}_{#2}}\,}%
}
\newcommand{\hplus}{{\mspace{-\medmuskip}}+}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\begin{aligned}
x^2+6x+10 
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{\hplus 2x (3)}_{+2ab} + 10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{\hplus2x (3)}_{+2ab} \underbrace{+(3)^2 -(3)^2}_{+b^2-b^2} +10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2+2x(3)+(3)^2}_{a^2+2ab+b^2}  -(3)^2 +10\\
&= \underbrace{(x+3)^2}_{(a+b)^2} -9 +10\\
&= (x+3)^2+1
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\let\temp\underbrace
\def\underbrace#1_#2{{\color{red}\temp{{\color{black}{\strut}#1{}}}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\openup1\jot
\begin{aligned}
x^2+6x+10 
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{+2x (3)}_{+2ab} + 10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2}_{a^2} \underbrace{+2x (3)}_{+2ab} \underbrace{+(3)^2 -(3)^2}_{+b^2-b^2} +10\\
&= \underbrace{x^2+2x(3)+(3)^2}_{a^2+2ab+b^2}  -(3)^2 +10\\
&= \underbrace{(x+3)^2}_{(a+b)^2} -9 +10\\
&= (x+3)^2+1
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

`{}` so + gets infix spacing, added `\strut` so the braces are all at same depth, and added `\openup` to increase the line spacing a bit.

Comment: your example doesn't use `align*` ??

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity the same, before the environment